# jQuery UI Autocomplete DownArrow UpArrow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, arrow-keys

I am having some issues with jQuery Autocomplete and moving DownArrow and UpArrow ?

The problem seems to be that

`<input id="autocomplete-input" value="">`

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
       $('#autocomplete-input').val(ui.item.label);
 }
```

This works great for MOUSE focus - but when I use `arrowUp` and `arrowDown` - it selects the `ui.item.id` over and above the `ui.item.label`

How can I fix this so that either:

1. the `input` val isn't changed at all [i.e. it keeps the users
   inputted term]
2. it updates the `input` val with the `focused` val the user is on with keydown/keyup

thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Make sure to prevent the default behavior of the `focus` event:

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
    this.value = ui.item.label;
      // or $('#autocomplete-input').val(ui.item.label);

    // Prevent the default focus behavior.
    event.preventDefault();
      // or return false;
}
```

Comment: aha! awesome thanks so much @andrew - i totally forgot to try that :)

Comment: This is working but one issue when key(up/down) is at selected item text box is showing value not label but after pressing enter its again showing value