# How to type name of the column but save the foreign key as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an autocomplete field on my productline table, where i type the a food name and find it. However, i dont want to save this value, instead: i want to save the food_id!

see my autocomplete field on my view:

```html
<%= f.autocomplete_field :prl_desc, autocomplete_calorie_cal_desc_productlines_path, class: 'linestringinput', placeholder: "Parent Food" %>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443012/rails-how-do-i-autocomplete-search-for-name-but-save-id . I don't believe it's supported out of the box, you'll need to have the controller return a label + id then add some JS to capture the id into a hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/risuiowa/rails-jquery-autocomplete#getting-the-object-id) are the details of setting id of the selected object.

If you need to use the id of the selected object, you can use the id_element attribute too:

```
f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path, :id_element => '#some_element'
```

This will update the field with id *#some_element with the id of the selected object. The value for this option can be any jQuery selector.

Comment: dear wasipeer, thank you for the right direction, but in the documentation i did not find anything about how to define #some_element. Can you please explain this further? Thank you!